# Is it possible and safe to use deterministic UUID for access control?

Tags: security, database-design, uuid, uniqueidentifier

Consider that there is a multi-tenant platform, and users can view all resources owned by the organization to which they belong, and cannot view any other orgs' resources. If all resource UUIDs are generated using a deterministic UUID with their owner org's UUID as their namespace, can the owner org of any resource be determined with just the org UUID, the UUID of the resource, and the deterministic UUID method?

I'm led to this idea from highly deterministic bitcoin wallets, where an initial private key is used to generate all subsequent private keys in the wallet (possibly incorrect paraphrase), so that you can always generate the same private keys again from just the original one.

Answer (score 1):

Typically multi-tenant environments have stronger tenant isolation than just an owner org UUID.  Generally, UUID values have a non-deterministic component.  If you're working with a deterministic UUID, someone could infer another owner org's value.  At that point it would seem, deterministic UUID = int identity.  If an attacker can specify the UUID value, they would be vulnerable.

The question you might be bringing up is whether being inconspicuous provides protection.  While being conspicuous may put a bigger target on your back, random inconspicuous people have their identity stolen all the time.  Real security is with keys not algorithms.

Comment: I guess I left out an important detail. The company UUID wouldn't be used like a secret, it would just be used to identify whether a company owns some other resource. An authenticated user would provide their authentication token (such as OAuth2 for example), and from that token the user's information would be requested from the authentication system, including the company UUID. The company UUID could be stored with every resource and compared that way, or if UUIDs can be deterministic based on the original company UUID, you don't even need to store the company UUID on every resource.

Comment: We could get into security methods for multi tenant environments like using separate DB tables or separate DBs for each company, but my question is about the capabilities of deterministic UUIDs.

Comment: Are you considering normal uuid vs. non-deterministic uuid?  It's not clear why they're appealing to your use case, clearly you have some reservations about using them.  Why wouldn't you just use a 64 bit int?